# Post request of an exe application

Tags: post, request, exe

I have a question as to whether something is possible.  I have an exe application I use on a daily basis.  This application allows me to fill in data and when I save it, the data is saved to a database in the cloud.

Now this application does not have an API.  I have developed a custom tool and I need to somehow get the data in my custom tool to the cloud database this exe file is on.

Is it possible to view the post request this exe application is making to the cloud, and then replicate this call within my app?

Thanks

Comment: You can try using wireshark to "sniff" the network traffic

Comment: you can use fiddler to see the requests

Comment: Ok, thought I could do something like that.  But is is possible to replicate this request in my own application?

Comment: actually this depends on how the original application sends data, if it's a plain POST should be replicable (as long as there is no authorization involved)